# I can't see all images in my media library - How Can I reset the index of that library?

Tags: images, uploads, media-library

When I load my media library (either through the media tab on the left or editing posts/pages and adding images in that interface) it shows that I have 1206 images in my site.  However when I click load more it loads some, and I can click "load more" again more load.  This is repeatable until I hit 343 images.  Then no more will load no matter how many times I click "load More".  It always stops at 343.

Is there a way to reset the media library and have WordPress re-index the library?  I've gone into myPHPadmin and checked the db (analyze, fix, check, and repair tables).

Comment: Does the number stay at 343 even if you delete or add other images?